# Prompt for an optional IntRange with click.prompt

Tags: python, python-click

I want to prompt the user to enter an integer within a range, or to allow an empty value to move on:

```py
import click

numbers = []
while True:
    num = click.prompt("Enter a number", type=click.IntRange(1, 10), default=None)
    if not num:
        break
    numbers.append(num)

print(f"List of numbers: {numbers}")
```

I was hoping to see this:

```sh
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number:
List of numbers: [1, 2]
```

but instead the loop runs forever. How can I specify that I'm happy to allow `None` as an input, but get the benefits of using `IntRange`?

Comment: You want loop to break when None is passed ?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that the user can keep adding integers until they've added enough, at which point they just press Enter and the loop quits.

Comment: It works as you'd expect if you have a default of `""`, not sure if this is viable for you

Comment: @Sayse it would not work since OP has put the constraint of IntRange. You would get error `Error: '' is not a valid integer range.` if `default=""` is used.

Comment: @gsb22 - [works ok as far as i can tell](https://ideone.com/HCnS7f)

Comment: @Sayse wow.. Doesn't work for me. https://replit.com/@gsb22/ShortFrivolousApi#main.py 

Maybe different version I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the documentation --> https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/?highlight=click%20prompt#click.prompt

> default (Optional[Any]) – the default value to use if no input
> happens. If this is not given it will prompt until it’s aborted.

The default value you mention will be used as input if the user simply presses enter. Since you have provided `None` to it, `click` will keep on prompting for the response because it didn't get one.
`None is default and not considered as input.`

Also, since you have provided a range(1,10), you can't set anything other than [1-10] `both included` in default, otherwise it will throw error.

Now, what I have understood for your use case, you want to process all the values from 1-10 and if user just presses enter, you want to break out of loop.

Following code should direct you.

```
import click

numbers = []
while True:
    num = click.prompt("Enter a number", type=click.IntRange(0, 10), default=0)
    if not num:
        break
    numbers.append(num)

print(f"List of numbers: {numbers}")
```

**Output**

```
Enter a number [0]: 1
Enter a number [0]: 2
Enter a number [0]: 3
Enter a number [0]: 
List of numbers: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This works, but it's not _quite_ doing the same thing. You're assigning a value from the allowed range to represent NULL. That's not too bad here, but what if the validation is a date? Which date should represent NULL?

Comment: you can use Unix epoch time for the same. 01/01/1970 I think. In that you have to compare the exact value of data and not None.

Comment: Also, if you want to your custom default, you are better off not using type.

Answer (score 0):

One route (though it feels a bit like a hack) is to [create a custom type](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/parameters/#implementing-custom-types) which makes the specified type optional:

```py
import click


class OptionalParamType(click.ParamType):
    def __init__(self, param_type: click.ParamType):
        self.param_type = param_type

    def convert(self, value, param, ctx):
        if not value:
            return
        return self.param_type.convert(value, param, ctx)
```

This allows us to specify anything Falsy as the default (except `None`) and things work as we'd hoped:

```py
In [8]: numbers = []

In [9]: while True:
   ...:     num = click.prompt("Number (or enter to stop)", type=OptionalParamType(click.IntRange(1, 10)), default="", show_default=False)
   ...:     if not num:
   ...:         break
   ...:     numbers.append(num)
   ...:
Number (or enter to stop): 5
Number (or enter to stop): 10
Number (or enter to stop): 20
Error: 20 is not in the range 1<=x<=10.
Number (or enter to stop):

In [10]: numbers
Out[10]: [10, 5]
```

Comment: I was actually checking this myself as well. And, no this is not heck. This is perfect to create you own ParamType on top of default ones.